# How to apply a dprep package to incoming data in score.py Azure Workbench

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I had been wondering if it were possible to apply "data preparation" (.dprep) files to incoming data in the score.py, similar to how Pipeline objects may be applied.  This would be very useful for model deployment. To find out, I asked this question on the MSDN forums and received a [response](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/640e93c3-0b88-4668-9869-91da85f7f1e3/purpose-of-dprep-files-azure-machine-learning-workbench?forum=MachineLearning) confirming it were possible, but little explanation about how to actually do it.  The response was:

> in your score.py file, you can invoke the dprep package from Python
>   SDK to apply the same transformation to the incoming scoring data.
>   make sure you bundle your .dprep file in the image you are building.

So my questions are:

- What function do I apply to invoke this dprep package?

  - Is it: `run_on_data(user_config, package_path, dataflow_idx=0, secrets=None, spark=None)` ?
- How do I bundle it into the image when creating a web-service from the CLI?

  - Is there a switch to `-f` for score files?

I have scanned through the entire [documentation](https://opdhsblobprod01.blob.core.windows.net/contents/4a6d75bb3af747de838e6ccc97c5d978/fc2d1c1c13c843cb9c6ca45d2038633b?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=gDlMGB31l0tV%2FBrLS6R1B0qeKhuGoKppykGocKHslSo%3D&st=2018-06-22T10%3A29%3A14Z&se=2018-06-23T10%3A39%3A14Z&sp=r) and [Workbench Repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/tree/master/articles/machine-learning/desktop-workbench) but cannot seem to find any examples.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:

Scenario:

1. I import my data from a live database and let's say this data set has 10 columns.
2. I then feature engineer this (.dsource) data set using the Workbench resulting in a .dprep file which may have 13 columns.
3. This .dprep data set is then imported as a pandas DataFrame and used to train and test my model.
4. Now I have a model ready for deployment.
5. This model is deployed via Model Management to a Container Service and will be fed data from a live database which once again will be of the original format (10 columns).
6. Obviously this model has been trained on the transformed data (13 columns) and will not be able to make a prediction on the 10 column data set.

What function may I use in the 'score.py' file to apply the same transformation I created in workbench?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found what you need.

From [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/desktop-workbench/data-prep-python-execution-api) you would import from the `azureml.dataprep` package.

There aren't any examples there, but searching on GitHub, I found [this file](https://github.com/wmeints/azuremeetup-machinelearning/blob/6cad78ee53cb7e347b4ebd563306ce3a6cab3805/challenge-3/starters/train.py) which has the following to run data preparation.

```
from azureml.dataprep import package

df = package.run('Data analysis.dprep', dataflow_idx=0)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the answer however that's not exactly what I'm looking for.  That function will create a DataFrame from a dprep package that you have already prepared in Workbench itself.  I'm looking for a function to run from within the `score.py` file.  I'm looking to apply the same transformation but on new **incoming** data.  I'll update my post with an example scenario.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood what the question was. Just from looking further in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/desktop-workbench/model-management-service-deploy), I wonder if the `generate_schema` and the `ModelDataCollector` do some magic on the input data. Hard to say, though....

Comment: And all the examples I've come across hardcode their own input data :/

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like this can be achieved by using the `run_on_data(user_config, package_path, dataflow_idx=0, secrets=None, spark=None)` method from the `azureml.dataprep.package` module.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/desktop-workbench/data-prep-python-execution-api) :

> `run_on_data(user_config, package_path, dataflow_idx=0, secrets=None, spark=None)` runs the specified data flow based on an in-memory data source and returns the results as a dataframe. The `user_config` argument is a dictionary that maps the absolute path of a data source (.dsource file) to an in-memory data source represented as a list of lists.